# Books on logic and ZFC set theory for physicist

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am undergraduate student in physics with not that many mathematics courses done in my career. Nevertheless, I am very interested in mathematical physics. I started studying from the lectures "Geometrical anatomy of theoretical physics" which can be found at https://youtu.be/V49i_LM8B0E.

From the lectures I have gained some sort of intuition but I feel that for my satisfaction I want to learn a little bit more. For you to better understand my interests, I want to mention what kind of things I would like to learn next. The general idea is that I do not want to go very deep in these exciting and interesting topics but I want to know enough so that I can learn topics like topology, manifolds, bundles and so on that are necessary for physics without stumbling across things that come from logic or set theory. For example, while I can prove basic things in topology (which basically just use set-theoretical arguments), I am sometimes dissatisfied because I can prove things "intuitively" but if some day I wanted to make my proofs formal, I am afraid that I couldn't. This is certainly something I would like to change.

1. Propositional and predicate logic. Proofs and rules of inference.

I feel satisfied with classical logic which defined proposition and predicate in an intuitive way and which defined operators using truth tables. This is enough rigor for me and I am willing to accept this. I am also willing to accept the philosophy that logic goes first and then I use it to tell what set theory is. The thing I have the most problems with in logic is how to make formal proof. In the lectures I heard the recipe (proof is sequence of propositions which are either axioms, tautologies or "modus ponens"), but I have trouble proving many things as I am unsure if I am doing it right. I would be happy for some reference that could show some examples on how to make formal proofs, so that I would have a nice feeling that if someone in the future would not believe my proof then I could go back to logic and write a nice, billion lines long formal proof.

2. ZFC set theory.

My whole life I have been using "naive set theory" without a doubt but once I got introduced to Russell's paradox I feel uneasy about it. That is indeed possible that in my whole physics career I will always be able to prove and write everything in terms of naive set theory, but something just feels wrong. That being said, I would like to receive some reference about ZFC set theory for beginners. I am not interested in some deep topics in the set theory - I just want to be sure that I know what axioms are (that are now considered to be consistent) so that I could consult them whenever I get too confused in my mathematical journey.

I would appreciate any suggestions and/or comments from your personal experience!

Comment: Others may correct me, but I am not sure if ZFC set theory and axiomatic proof systems are really the best systems to work with for any kind of underpinning of physics. Axiomatic proof systems can be a bear to work with, and there are far more user-friendly proof systems, with just as much mathematical rigor. As far as set theory goes I am a little less confident in my pronouncements (maybe there are important connections between the axioms of ZFC and theretical physics?), but I would think that 'naive set theory' might be rigorous enough for your purposes. So .... what is your goal here?

Comment: Hmm, I do not see why a physicist would want to approach these topics any differently than a mathematician would.

Comment: I am very quickly browsing through that lecture series ... I see plenty of logic, algebra, and set theory, but so far I see nothing that would require you to go too deep into axiomatic systems for logic. Yes, you want to know the basic language of logic, so you can read quantified expressions, but personally I see no need to delve all that deeply into logic theory as this instructor does in his first lecture.

Comment: Mathematicians almost never write formal proofs. I don't see why a physicist ever would. And don't worry about Russell's paradox. In physics, you will never have worry about sets being elements of themselves or any other such pathological sets. If you have to remember anything from ZFC, it's probably just that you should never define a subset in terms of itself. Not that I think you would ever want to. A book on mathematical logic may well needlessly confuse you. And you will probably never use any of it in physics. You will need to know the basic rules of logic, how to manipulate quantifiers.

Comment: I would recommend finding a logic book that uses [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) or a similar proof system. The notion of proof you've described is known as a [Hilbert-style proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert-style_system), but these are not human-friendly. They are designed to be minimal to simplify meta-logical proofs *about* the proof system.

Comment: There are many good introducory textbooks for math log: you can find posts in this site (reference-request).

Comment: An old book (difficult but interesting): J.Sneed, [The Logical Structure of Mathematical Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=ypruCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (\971).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Interestingly, I actually have a (hardback print) copy of Sneed's book, which I got in a used bookstore a very long time ago (around 1977 or 1978). It's one those books I know is scholarly, but every so often (ranges from intervals of a few months to several years) when I glance through it, I find myself wondering who the intended audience is and whether anything in it would be of interest to a physicist or to a logician. It strikes me as something way, way down some rabbit hole that leads to nowhere. At least, that's my impression.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: I noticed you link the 1979 2nd edition, and being curious whether that is the edition I have (which would mean I got "1977 or 1978" incorrect), I looked at the copy I have. My copy of Sneed's book is the 1971 1st edition, and I'm now pretty sure "1977 or 1978" is correct. I also recall spending very little money on it, probably $1 or less). Figures 3-1, 3-2, 3-3 on pp. 176-178 (pages might slightly differ in 1979 edition) bring back memories, when I thought as I got advanced enough in math and physics, that this would all seem "well known" stuff. This never happened . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - 2nd **revised** ed is a paperback one dated 1979.